# Replace null value as text in the original table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle SQL and here is my table:

FILM (Catalog_Num, Format, Title, Year, Number_Discs, Rating, Timing, Genre)

If some value in rating are null, how can I change all the null value into the text NR ?

Here is what I tried, but how can I let the column title of NR be rating, instead of (NVL, RATING, 'NR')

```
SELECT RATING, nvl(RATING,'NR')
FROM FILM
WHERE RATING IS NULL;

RATING        NVL(RATING,'NR
------------- -----------------
              NR
              NR
              NR
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, next time please don't show an image, but copy and paste this as text. You can use the {} button to keep the format. (Just try it. Edit your request and try to replace the image with the text.)

Comment: Thanks! I've edited it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give each column in your result a name:

```
SELECT
  rating AS rating_with_nulls,
  NVL(rating, 'NR') AS rating
FROM film
ORDER BY rating_with_nulls;
```

This is called a column alias. The `AS` is optional.

You find it in the syntax diagrams in the docs here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702. Look for "select_list" and you'll see `expr [AS] c_alias`. It may take some time to get used to these diagrams, but then they become really helpful.

Sometimes it is not a good idea to name the result like a column. In above example, what if we had `ORDER BY rating`? What would `rating` refer to? The original column or the expression result where nulls are replaced with 'NR'?

`NVL` is Oracle specific by the way. The standard SQL function for this situation is `COALESCE`. It is okay to use `NVL`, but it's always good to know that it is Oracle only and what to use in another DBMS, I think.

Answer (score 0):

use `coalesce()`

```
select coalesce(rating,'NR')
```

your rating column need to be varchar data type

or use `NVL`

```
NVL( string1, replace_with )
```

The value returned if string1 is null.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT nvl(rating, 'Nr') rating from film